# Loading levels from xml and supporting screen resolutions in Ios

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game that uses levels. The levels are made at a default scene width and height resolution.

The thing i am worried about is when the game is played on IPads iphone 5′s etc, the position of sprites loaded from the level xml files will be out of place due to the screen size.

In my case, could someone tell me the best thing to do in this situation or some advice on the approach i should take?

Also if any has experienced this, please let me know.

Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally this has nothing to do with how or where you store the level data.

These are the standard approaches, which one works for you depends on your requirements and desired results:

1. design each screen resolution individually (error-prone, tedious)
2. design for one screen resolution, then scale up or down according to screen aspect ratio (can lead to skewing as the screen size scaling for width & height are likely to be different)
3. design for the smallest screen resolution, then center the contents on the screen (this leaves unused areas either at the top/bottom or left/right sides)
4. same as above, but zoom content to fill the screen (this will remove the letterboxing, but also partially remove one side's content from the view)

In essence this is the [same problem as movies have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterbox) in trying to fit to screens of varying aspect ratios.

In general this is all a matter of scaling the input (positions) to a desirable output. The easiest approach is to maintain aspect ratio and allow for letterboxing. However Apple may reject letterboxing apps if nothing is done to hide the letterboxes (black areas) since Apple requires apps to support widescreen resolution, and letterboxing does not normally fall into their definition of "supporting widescreen".